# Bootstrap showing as one column instead of two

Tags: bootstrap-4

Title pretty much says it all. I'd expect to see two columns, which isn't happening. Would really appreciate any help. Code can be found here: https://codepen.io/jar5/pen/NWWXBro

I've done a lot of Googling and tested every solution I could find.

I cut some of the items in the list to save space, but you can see the full code at the codepen link.

```
<div>
  <div id="question" class="col-6">
    <h2>Question 1:</h2>
    <p>Here's a question with choices</p>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <label for="0">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input id="0" type="radio" name="answer" value="0">Choice 1
        </li>
      </label>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 infobox">
    <h4>This should be on the next column</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

No error messages. The `<h4>` at the bottom should be showing up in a second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `style="display: block;"` from the `<div class="row" id="quiz">`. The `row` class has `flex` property in bootstrap 4 to allow displaying children with `col-` class in columns so your code should look something like this

```html
<div class="row" id="quiz">
  <div id="question" class="col-6">...</div>
  <div class="col-3 infobox">...</div>
</div>
```